# How do I prevent Selenium from downloading certain "Sources" from a web-page?

Tags: javascript, selenium, google-chrome

I am using *Selenium* for some web-scraping activities, and I really feel the need to **limit data consumption** by **blocking specific file types** or filenames from being downloaded. I wish to block them by **regex** filters, like:

- `*.MP4`
- `*.css`
- `*ads.google.com*`

So far I have not found any solutions and I am looking forward for a *JavaScript* one, if possible...

Comment: Would you accept an answer in Java?

Comment: @DebanjanB yes, absolutely - as long as the solution comes with it!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to be achievable by mediating a **Chrome Extension** middleware.

Particularily, in `background-scripts`, you could use `onBeforeRequests` to handle and filter each single request

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
        function(info) {
            return {cancel: info.url.toLowerCase().includes('.css') || info.url.toLowerCase().includes('.gif') || info.url.toLowerCase().includes('.png') || info.url.toLowerCase().includes('.jpg') || info.url.toLowerCase().includes('.jpeg') || info.url.toLowerCase().includes('.webm') || info.url.toLowerCase().includes('.webp') ||info.url.toLowerCase().includes('.mp4') || info.url.toLowerCase().includes('allHeaderNonBlocking.js') || info.url.toLowerCase().includes('allHeader.js?') || info.url.toLowerCase().includes('/analytics.js') || info.url.toLowerCase().includes('googletagmanager') || info.url.toLowerCase().includes('calleo-livechat') || info.url.toLowerCase().includes('.svg') };
        },
        {
            urls: ["<all_urls>"]
        },
        ["blocking"]
    );
```